# What are the ways to deploy python code on aws ec2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, ffmpeg

I have a python project and i want to deploy it on an AWS EC2 instance. My project has dependencies to other python libraries and uses programs installed on my machine. What are the alternatives to deploy my project on an AWS EC2 instance?
Further details : My project consist on a celery periodic task that uses ffmpeg and blender to create short videos.
I have checked elastic bean stalk but it seems it is tailored for web apps. I don't know if containerizing my project via docker is a good idea...

The manual way and the cheapest way to do it would be :
1- Launch a spot instance
2- git clone the project
3- Install the librairies via pip
4- Install all dependant programs
5- Launch periodic task

I am looking for a more automatic way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beanstalk is certainly an option.   You don't necessarily have to use it for web apps and you can configure all of the dependencies needed via .ebextensions.

Containerization is usually my go to strategy now.   If you get it working within Docker locally then you have several deployment options and the whole thing gets much easier since you don't have to worry about setting up all the dependencies within the AWS instance.

Once you have it running in Docker you could use Beanstalk, ECS or CodeDeploy.

Comment: Thank you Rick, i have studied the possibilities you mentionned and i am going to use docker and ECS.

Comment: Good call.   If you ever get to wanting to use some CI, such as circleci I have a git repo explaining the process here:  http://ricktbaker.com/2017/08/30/docker-circleci-aws-ecr-ecs/ .   CircleCi has a free tier, so might be worth checking out.